# 12.10 boots to black screen

Tags: boot, 12.10, intel-graphics, asus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Sometimes(most of them), I get a black screen after the booting. It's doing that since last monday after an update. I can get to the console/terminal with ALT+ CTRL F1 but when i ask to reboot it doesn't work. I have a failure in the process.

Sometimes i get a screen with a lower resolution... and sometimes i get a freeze with a purple screen.

And sometimes it works..

My computer it's ASUS k52F with an intel HD graphics card.

Thanks

Comment: What version of the Ubuntu?

Comment: I have ubuntu 12.10

Comment: So add a proper tag to your post, because I cannot do it. It will provide more information for others [;